# Dual ListBox not displaying options from database on first run

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I am using Bootstrap Dual Listbox that I got from `http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/`

After trying to implement it, I encounter a single problem. At first run, the options are not being displayed on either select box unless I click the `Move All` button.

So here is the structure as well as the codes.

> **Index.php**

```
<!-- HTML -->

<select multiple="multiple" size="5" class="eItems" name="skillsTagged" id="skillsTagged">

</select>

<!-- Scripts-->

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  var dlb1 = $('#skillsTagged').bootstrapDualListbox({
    nonSelectedListLabel: 'Non-selected',
    selectedListLabel: 'Selected',
    preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
    moveOnSelect: false                     
  });

  getSkills();

});

function getSkills(){

  var oldid = "1";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_selected_skills.php",
    data: { specId : oldid }
  }).done(function( res ) {
    $("#skillsTagged").html(res);
  });

}

</script>
```

> **get_selected_skills.php**

```
<?php

  echo "<option value='1'>1</option><option selected value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option selected value='5'>5</option>";

?>
```

So it seems like the options are there but are not being displayed on first run. Tried it on a regular listbox and is working so if anyone already encountered this when using Dual Listbox, your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about this Duel Listbox, but there's not enough info in your question to track down the problem. It seems that on document ready the `getSkills();` function is called, but all I can see is a `getSkillsEdit();` function. So edit your question and show us the correct function.

Comment: @icecub Sorry its a typo. Edited it now!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ajax async property to false...

İn method : async:false

Or globally:

$.ajaxSetup({
    async:false
});